# Configuration Error For MySql Profile Provider

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

**Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message**: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 160:        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
Line 161:        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
Line 162:        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 163:      </providers>
Line 164:    </roleManager>
```

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config    Line: 162

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' could not be loaded.

Comment: Nice error...now whats the question?

Comment: how to solve this error? what the reason this error occured.and use sql server not use mysql